# Getting error "String index out of range: 0" on using String Builder

Tags: java, string

So this is my code in Java (for returning two halves of a string - one is the odd half, starting with the index 0, or the first character, and the second half, starting with the index 1, or the second character):

```
public class StringTest{
     public String halfOfString(String message, int start){
            int length = message.length();
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(length); 
            char ch;
            int i;
            if((start==0)||(start==1)){
               for(i=start; i<message.length(); i=i+2){
                            ch = message.charAt(i);
                            output.setCharAt(i,ch); // error occurs here
               }

            }
     return output.toString();
     }

     public void testFunction(){
           String s = "My name is Sid";
           String first = halfOfString(s, 0);
           String second = halfOfString(s, 1);
           System.out.println("First half is " + first + " and second half is " + second);
     }
}
```

So my problem is - whenever I attempt to run this program on BlueJ IDE, it doesn't, and returns the error in the title, on the line mentioned in the comment.

I have poured over this site for a similar question which may help me with my error, but all I found was a question which suggested a change I have already implemented (in the StringBuilder setCharAt method, the person had reversed the i and ch parameters).

Is it anything to do with the fact that the "output" is declared empty at first, and the setCharAt method can only replace the characters which already exist? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Is it anything to do with the fact that the "output" is declared empty at first,  and the setCharAt method can only replace the characters which already exist? Any help would be greatly appreciated." -- Yes

Comment: are you sure `message` is not empty? (i.e message.length should be > 0) ?

Comment: [`output.append()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char%29)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - Thanks for the info, now I know what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @Yazan - No, definitely sure that "message" was not empty.

Comment: @khelwood - Thanks for the answer, it worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it anything to do with the fact that the "output" is declared empty at first, and the setCharAt method can only replace the characters which already exist?

Yes, that is exactly why you get this error.

Note that creating a `StringBuilder` with a specified length, as you are doing:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(length);
```

does **not** create a `StringBuilder` which already has that many characters - it just creates a `StringBuilder` with that internal buffer size. The `StringBuilder` itself still contains no characters, so trying to set the first character will result in the exception that you get.

Call `append` on the `StringBuilder` to add characters instead of `setCharAt`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. And is there any way I could improve this program? As in, is there any simpler way to split the string into two halves?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it anything to do with the fact that the "output" is declared empty
>   at first, and the setCharAt method can only replace the characters
>   which already exist?

Yes, that's the reason.

The Javadoc of `setCharAt` is clear on this:

> The index argument must be greater than or equal to 0, and **less than
>   the length of this sequence**.

Why don't you just use the `append` method in StringBuilder? It looks to me like, if your code would work, it would leave holes in the StringBuilder since you're only setting every other character and not the ones in between. Using `append` ensures that there are no holes.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner to Java, and I often end up making mistakes, and then read up on the documentation. Thanks for the answer! So when should I use the setCharAt method?

Comment: You can use setCharAt when you have already appended a character and then you want to change it. But - I've been programming in Java since 1995 and I've never had to use that method. YMMV